# JDBC Kafka connector is not supporting decrementing primary key

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-data

Recently we started working on a project to consume Oracle DB and push data to confluent kafka connector topic, but we ran into these issue:

1. Our DB is using decrementing primary key and Confluent Kafka doesn't have the decrementing primary key.
2. Our DB doesn't have a timestamp.

I'm building a spring Boot application that reads about a million records per day from oracle DB, process these records, and pushes them into kafka topic.

and it seems like that JDBC Kafka connector is not supporting decrementing primary key, I wonder if anyone ran into this issue?
and what alternative solution is available to meet these requirements?

Comment: Amount of data shouldn't matter. What have you tried and what issues are you running into? Your two options are the same thing - both will require storing data in memory for some amount of time before sending to "next process"/Kafka ... You're going to basically be doing the same thing as the JDBC source connector, anyway.

Comment: The DB we have doesn't have a timestamp, and that's necessary for JDBC connector to work, we can't proceed with it unless they support that in the future. 

What kind of in-memory solution you suggest for this kind of scenario?

Comment: You can set the JDBC connector to work on incrementing primary keys. Timestamp is only one supported mode. Uh, an arraylist would work fine

Comment: The DB I have has a decrementing primary key, and JDBC connector doesn't support it as of now. :(

Comment: Alright. You could still try to use Debezium. There shouldn't be any data model that does not work with

Comment: That's great :) Can Debezium publish all existed records initially and publish the changed records moving forward?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's the default behavior. [Please refer docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.9/connectors/oracle.html#how-the-oracle-connector-works)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far, one last question about Debezium that I couldn't find answer for, does it support join query? or is it per Table?

Comment: Per table. You would need to use Kafka Streams to join created topics into a unified Kafka topic